# Minimize a function with respect to a matrix

Tags: machine-learning, multivariate-analysis, optimization, matrix

I have two sets of vectors, `A` and `B`. Vectors from set `A` live in an m-dimensional space, while those from set `B` are n-dimensional.

I also have a mapping `f` from `A` to `B`. I would like to learn an `n x m` matrix Q such that the following sum is minimized:

$$ \sum_{v \in A}{\|Qv - f(v)\|^2}$$

Are there any standard approaches to tackle this, for example in Matlab?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just do multiple linear regression for each of the $n$ dimensions independently and take each set of $m$ coefficients as a row in $Q$. Since square root is monotone for positive real numbers it is not hard to convince yourself that if for all $i$, $Q_{i,*}\in \mathbb{R}^m$ minimizes

$$
 \sum_{v \in A} \left\|Q_{i,*}v - f(v)_i\right\|^2
$$

Then $Q \in \mathbb{R}^{n \times m}$, where each $Q_{i,*}$ is a row in $Q$, minimizes

$$
 \sum_{v \in A} \left\|Qv - f(v)\right\|^2.
$$